# Copying blob from private blob container to public blob container in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We have two blob containers on Azure Storage. One is private and the other is public. I want to make a blob in private container a publicly accessible one on my application.

I am trying **to copy blob from private to public container**. I have found this on [docs - Copy Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob). However, I could not manage to successfully to this operation and cannot find detailed explanations.

Last error I get is about `Authorization` header are not formed properly. Another previous one was about `Date` header not proper but I have solved it by `new Date().toUTCString()` instead of `new Date()`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems that you're using rest api, why not use sdk?

Comment: I am connecting from Node.js. I will check if there is an sdk for it.

Comment: The sdk is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node#microsoft-azure-storage-sdk-for-nodejs-and-javascript-for-browsers), you use the method startCopyBlob within the sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you can use [node.js sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node#microsoft-azure-storage-sdk-for-nodejs-and-javascript-for-browsers), then use the method [startCopyBlob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.core.js#L2176). By using rest api, it will take a few time to construct the authentication and not easy.

Comment: I am trying the node.js sdk now and the startCopyBlob method. I get an error says: `The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.`

Comment: `// Copy Blob
      blobService.startCopyBlob(
        `${req.user.id}/${sceneId}/${fileName}`,
        AZURE_STORAGE_PUBLIC_CONTAINER_NAME,
        `${sceneId}/${fileName}`,
        blobResult => {
          console.log("blobResult: ", blobResult);
          res.json({ body: { blobResult: blobResult } });
        }
      );`

Comment: here I log and return the `blobResult` to see how everything goes. Note the target blob uri lacks uer id since it s public and we did not wanted to expose a user's id with a response to public request.

Comment: I have needed to give the full uri for the source blob file in the first parameter nad it worked.